# check a List of values in db and retrieve items that fall under a Date Time Month Property

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Please guys,
What i want to achieve is to get the previous 6 month back  and search through my Transactions Table and retrieve a list of transactions that fall under each month property of Date Time and sum thier amount.

forexample. the current date is 04/03/2020 the last 6 months date becomes `02/20,01/2020,12/2019,11/2019,10/2019,09/2019` now i want to search through a table `transactions` which has a `DateTime` Property `DateCreated` and retrieve all the transactions that occurred within `each month` and sum all their amount.

`ResponseCode 00 means successful payment`
what i have tried.

```
 List<DateTime> months = new List<DateTime>();
    List<double> MonthSum= new List<Double>();        
            DateTime[] lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i)).ToArray();

foreach (var month in lastSixMonths)
{
    var monthString = month.ToString("MM/yyyy");
            var trans = await _context.Transactions.Where(c => monthString.Contains(c.DateCreated.ToString()) && c.ResponseCode == "00").Select(c => c.Amount).ToListAsync();
            var sum = trans.Sum();
            MonthSum.Add(sum);

}
```

something seems to be wrong with how am doing this. please help

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you need:

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);
var sumByMonth = _context.Transactions.Where(d => d.CreateDate > fromDate)
                    .GroupBy(d => d.CreateDate.Month)
                    .Select(d => new { Month = d.Key, Sum = d.Sum(docs => docs.Amount) })
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Month , b => b.Sum);
```

Comment: Good answer. Based off the question, I believe OP is looking for the `fromDate` to be the first of the month though so all transactions in that month are returned. Ex: 6 months back is 9/4 but transactions are returned for 9/1 - Now.

Comment: good one but the from date should be a list of dates for the last 6 months

Comment: it needs additional group by year and it will be ok

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime field is displayed as "yyyy-MM-dd" in linq, so you need to change month to "yyyy-MM" for judgment.

In the where condition, the 'Contains' condition needs to be exchanged.

```
        List<DateTime> months = new List<DateTime>();
        List<double> MonthSum = new List<Double>();
        DateTime[] lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i)).ToArray();
        foreach (var month in lastSixMonths)
        {
            var monthString = month.ToString("yyyy-MM");
            var trans = await _context.Transactions.Where(c => c.DateCreated.ToString().Contains(monthString) && c.ResponseCode == "00").Select(c => c.Amount).ToListAsync();
            var sum = trans.Sum();
            MonthSum.Add(sum);

        }
```